# Applying Hausdorff Area formula with multiplicity

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I am trying to understand the following formula.

Let $f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant Lip $f$, $1 \leq n \leq m$. Then we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} H^0(f^{-1}(y) \cap A) dH^n(y) \leq (Lip \; f)^n L^n(A) $$

Where $H^0$ is the counting measure, and $f^{-1}(y) = \{ x : f(x) = y \}$.

Let $f: A = [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ be defined by $f(t) = (|t|, |t|)$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz with Lip $f =1$. EDIT: My error as pointed out by ArcticChar in the comments, the lipschitz constant is $\sqrt{2}$ so it all works out.

We have $H^0(f^{-1}(y) \cap A) = 0 $ except on $f(A)/ \{0\}$ where it's 2.

Then,

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} H^0(f^{-1}(y) \cap A) dH^1(y)  = 2 H^1(f(A)) = 2 \sqrt{2} $$

But the RHS of the inequality is $L^1([-1,1]) = 2$. What is wrong with my computation? EDIT: The error was earlier

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Lip}f$ in your example?

Comment: @ArcticChar the lipschitz constant

Comment: Yes, I mean what is the numerical value of this Lipschitz constant for $f(t) = (|t|, |t|)$?

Comment: Is it not equal one? OH its zero!

Comment: Ｗell, no. (check using the definition again)

Comment: @ArcticChar is it $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$